# How to destructure a string into first, middle, and last?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm writing a function to determine whether a number is a palindrome.

What I would like to do in the first case is to destructure the string into the first character, all the characters in the middle, and the last character. What I do is check if the first character is equal to the last, and then if so, proceed to check the middle characters.

What I have is below, but it generates type errors upon compilation.

```
numberIsPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
numberIsPalindrome n =
  case nString of
    (x:xs:y) -> (x == y) && numberIsPalindrome xs
    (x:y) -> x == y
    x -> True
  where nString = show n
```

Comment: Lists are linked lists (not arrays), so accessing the last is an expensive operation, which can not be performed through pattern matching. One can use the `last` library function for that, but it will be slow. It's much more efficient, and simpler,  to reverse the list and check for equality as suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `String` representation is cheating...

Not really, but this is more fun:

```
import Data.List

palindrome n = list == reverse list where
    list = unfoldr f n   
    f 0 = Nothing
    f k = Just (k `mod` 10, k `div` 10)
```

What it does is creating a list of digits of the number (`unfoldr` is really useful for such tasks), and then comparing whether the list stays the same when reversed.

What you try has several problems, e.g. you miss a conversion from the number to a `String` (which is just a list of `Char` in Haskell), and lists work completely different from what you try: Think of them more as stacks, where you usually operate only on one end.

That said, there is an `init` and a `last` function for lists, which allow to work your way from the "outer" elements of the list to the inner ones. A naive (and inefficient) implementation could look like this:

```
palindrome n = f (show n) where
    f [] = True
    f [_] = True
    f (x : xs) = (x == last xs) && (f (init xs))
```

But this is only for demonstration purposes, don't use such code in real live...

Comment: Some possible improvements: 1. Track the length of the list as you build it so you know when to stop comparing. 2. Use `quotRem` instead of `div` and `mod`. 3. Return false immediately if the argument is not zero but the least significant digit is zero. 4. Switch from lists to vectors to reduce allocation and pointer chasing.

Answer (score 1):

The definition you probably want is

```
numberIsPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
numberIsPalindrome num = let str = show num
                         in (str == reverse str)
```

Comment: It would have been nice if you had said "yes" to OP's stated strategy, helping them along, instead of replacing their ideas with your own

Answer (score 1):

The `(:)` operator is known as `cons`, it prepends items to lists:
`1:2:[]` results in `[1,2]`

You are getting a type error because you are trying to compare the first argument, a `Char`, with the last one, a `[a]`.

If you really would like to compare the first with the last you would use `head` and `last`.

But you are better using the solution that [taktoa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41388906/3847023) proposed:

```
numberIsPalindrome :: Int -> Bool
numberIsPalindrome num = 
    numberString == reverse numberString
  where numberString = show num
```

Comment: Note that if you call `last` in each iteration, the algorithm will be O(n^2) rather than O(n), because `last` is O(n).